# Calling mongoose from react client side

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, mongodb-query

Yes, I know I should call it from server side. But the purpose is to invoke MongoDB strait from the react-redux app. It's like firebase serverless apps do.
I write

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';

    let mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB);

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    let db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

And I get:

```
TypeError: __ 
WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_mongoose___default.a.connect is not a function
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you putting this code in your react app?

Comment: In one of redux saga.

Comment: The error you have shown is one usually due to putting something in a render or a return of a stateless functional component that is not a valid react child. The code you show here is not likely the cause for your error.

Answer (score 13):

From the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053837/react-native-cant-import-mongoose-on-the-front-endbut-it-works-from-the-back)

> Mongoose won't work in the frontend because it relies on functionality from Node which isn't present in browser JS implementations. You can't import Mongoose into frontend code.

---

Try importing mongoose in your react app

`import mongoose from "mongoose";`

and iterating through its properties:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mongoose).forEach(prop => {
  console.log(prop);
});
```

You'll get

```
Promise
PromiseProvider
Error
Schema
Types
VirtualType
SchemaType
utils
Document
```

The methods that you need to work with MongoDB, such as `connect`, are not being imported.

Answer (score 0):

mongoDB has to be initialized from the server. it is not like firebase that you can connect directly from the server. If you wanna do an operation from the client, you have to define an endpoint on the server, make a request from the client to this endpoint and handle this request on this endpoint. Since you are not clear what exactly you are trying to do, I will give you a simple example.

Let's say in one component you are fetching songs from the mongodb and rendering them to the screen and you wanna add a clear button to clear up the lists.

```
  <a href="/delete">
    <button>Clear the Screen</button>
  </a>
```

let's say I have a Song model defined in mongoose.

```
app.use("/delete", async (req, res) => {
  await Song.deleteMany();
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

I sent a request from the client, and server handled this CRUD operation.

NOTE that since you are making a request from the client to the server you have to set up proxy. Or you can use `webpack-dev-middleware` so express will serve the webpack files.

Answer (score 0):

You need [MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/realm/react-web-quickstart/)

Pseudo-Code Example :

```
import * as Realm from "realm-web";

const REALM_APP_ID = "<Your App ID>"; // e.g. myapp-abcde
const app = new Realm.App({ id: REALM_APP_ID });
```