# mongoose.connect() with react.js does not work and says that mongoose.connect() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a react.js app using node.js. I want to connect to my MongoDB database hosted on another computer in the same network. I type 
`mongoose.connect("mongodb://192.168.1.21:27017/testDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})`
But, when I run the react app and open it in my browser,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UhkH.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HWV8.png
I get these errors.

```
import React from 'react';
import Announcement from "../templates/Announcement.jsx"
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.1.11:27017/realmDB', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: String,
    postedOn: String,
    category: String
});

const Post = new mongoose.Model("Post", postSchema);

export default function() {
    const posts = Post.find({}, (err, post) => {
        return post
    })
    return <div>
        <div className="w3-card-4 w3-border w3-border-black inriasans mx-3" style={{marginTop: "1.5rem"}}>
            <header class="w3-container w3-light-gray w3-border-bottom w3-border-gray">
                <h3 class="inriasans"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> &nbsp;Announcements</h3>
            </header>
            <div class="w3-container pt-3 pb-3">
                <p class="w3-large">Get news related to NetherRealm here! You can also watch the <a href="#" className="w3-text-cyan">announcements</a> thread in the forums to get these announcements in your email.</p>
                <hr />
                {posts.map((post) => {
                    return <Announcement title={post.title} content={post.content} author={post.author} postedOn={post.postedOn} category={post.category} />
                })}
            </div>
            <footer class="w3-container w3-light-gray w3-border-top w3-border-gray pt-2">
                <p>View on the forums</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my code and [here](https://github.com/arnu515/netherrealm-home) is my source code.

Comment: You can't use mongoose on client side. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124721/calling-mongoose-from-react-client-side.

Comment: Is there another alternative?

Comment: You should setup a Node server to connect to Mongodb. It's not good practice to connect straight from client side to database.

Comment: I'm pretty new to node, can I have an example

Comment: Check this out maybe: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-your-first-mern-mongodb-express-js-react-js-and-node-js-stack-7e8b20463e66

Comment: alright, thanks! @huytc