# Mongoose model doesn't work when importing it in another Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I was trying to use my model to display and find users from the MongoDB,
But when I import it into **profile.js** and start my App it gives me an Error saying

- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Users')
  [image]

Note I Tried using it with the API and It works fine, Idk why it's like this with my Component,
It's weird to me because I never had this Error before, Anyone know how to fix it or why it's showing this Error?

> My code

**connect.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export default async function connect(){
    try{
        const {connection} = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
        if(connection.readyState = 1){
            return Promise.resolve(true)
        }
    }catch(err){
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}
```

**user.js**

```
import {Schema, models, model} from "mongoose";

const usersSchema = new Schema({
    ...
})

const Users = models.Users || model('Users', usersSchema)
export default Users
```

**profile.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {signOut, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import connect from "@/database/connect"
import Users from "@/database/schema/users"
export default function Profile(){
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoaded(true)
    }, [])

    const {data: session} = useSession()
    console.log(session)
    useEffect(() => {
        const userSession = session.user?.email
        if(session){
            const checkUserInfo = async() => {
                const findUser = await Users.findOne({ email: session.user?.email })
                console.log(findUser)
            } 
            checkUserInfo()  
        }
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: In your code, you don't call connect function, you just imported it, so probably there is no connection to the database to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I'm using the connect function now at the top of my function But it still shows the same Error.

Comment: I think you should be using mongo in the api directory and not inside a component, I could absolutely be wrong here, but it should be fully server side and then you can use axios or fetch to send requests from the client side to the api/database. 
Edit: I guess its not required to be in the api specifically, you could always use it in a getServerSideProps function

Comment: `mongoose` call can be called only on the server side code of next.js. api functions, middlewares etc. you cannot use it on client-side

Comment: I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124721/calling-mongoose-from-react-client-side) same as yours and you will find your answer there. Connect functionality is tied with node.js, so you won't be able to use it inside use effect in front end, you won't have mongoose connect module in front end to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In user.js
Remove the `default` keyword.
Your code would look like this

```
import {Schema, models, model} from "mongoose";

const usersSchema = new Schema({
    ...
})

export const Users = models.Users || model('Users', usersSchema)
```