# mongoose.connect is not a function - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, mongoose, passport.js

After messing around with my passport sessions and implementing JWTs along with them, I tried running my application but encountered a couple of errors that I can't wrap my head around:

> ERROR    TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function. (In 'mongoose.connect(config.MongoURL, {
> useNewUrlParser: true,
> useUnifiedTopology: true,
> useFindAndModify: false
> })', 'mongoose.connect' is undefined)

> ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

> ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

The thing that is making the errors a little bit confusing to me is the fact that the connection to my mongodb is actually made successfully, as I am able to `console.log(data)` in the promise right after the `mongoose.connect()` function with no errors being caught whatsoever. I also tried accessing my server side (using Postman) and doing some Get and Post functions that use my database and the requests were done successfully too!

As for the other two errors I have no idea what they mean.

Here's my **db/index.js** just in case:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/index');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose
  .connect(config.MongoURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`There was an error connecting to the database: ${err}`);
});
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: All the code shown is server-side one, yet you tagged this question as React Native and the errors shown (Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry) are of that domain... Can you elaborate more on how exactly this app is built and started?

Comment: @raina77ow yeah because i get these errors as soon as i run `npm start ios`; the app doesn't even build correctly. I'm just not sure whether it's a front-end or a server-side problem, hence the confusing tags and title. What does the 'Invariant Violation' error mean, maybe i could show or explain related code

Comment: What I think is happening here is that RN attempts to load `db/index` module too (because of dependencies or something), but fails to do it properly. Actually, all the rest of the code doesn't have much to do with the issue, so consider dropping it. What might be helpful is dependency tree - i.e., what does consume that file when code is started.

Comment: I also think this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053837/react-native-cant-import-mongoose-on-the-front-endbut-it-works-from-the-back - is partially related.

Comment: @raina77ow after reading through my front-end's landing screen's imports, I found a suspicious import statement that I don't recall using. I believe `import { states } from '../../server/db';` was also trying to load that index.js file but had problems doing that (just like you said).

Many thanks, the app builds now.

Comment: You're welcome. You can add this as answer yourself - or wait for me to do it. :)

Comment: @raina77ow I'm still confused as why would that cause a problem, even though the access to that file was only done through an import, not an actual use of related code. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the common thing when dealing with universal code: some parts might not work in browser, some - in Node. Sometimes it's good, because it simplifies separation of concerns, sometimes it's not, because you actually want some concern to be shared between those domains. But sometimes - and that's the worst case - it's shared when it shouldn't be.

This particular case is interesting because of two things.

First, as you mentioned, your build attempts to import from `db` some dependency for client-side code. That's not OK, as, in general, server-side DB should not be used on the client directly. And yes, `db/index.js` does not just define functions and types to export, but actually has some 'executable' statements. Compare this:

```
export default function someFunction() {
  // this is not invoked on import - only when `someFunction` is called!
  require('mongoose').connect('...');
}
```

... with the code you have right now.

Second, as noted in the linked question, `require('mongoose')` doesn't fail because it's actually can be used on both sides. Still, the very next *executable* statement does fail, because "client" mongoose does not have `connect` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

For those still confused by what was actually causing the errors, it was an `import { states } from '../../server/db';` at the beginning of one of my client-side screens. After removing it the app built successfully.

Refer to the accepted answer for a better understanding as why would that cause an error.